# Gsub a list with a list over a vector

Tags: r

I have a list of sentences stored as `data`. For each sentence in the list, I want to replace any words found in `to_replace` with the corresponding entry in `replace_with`.

I have constructed a simple function:

```
gsub.mult <- function(n) {
  obj <- gsub(to_replace[n], replace_with[n], data)
  return(obj)
}
```

Which I can then try to apply over the length of the indices

```
lapply(seq_along(to_replace), gsub.mult)
```

However, of course, this just returns a list, with a length of to_replace, that contains the original list of sentences each with only one gsub. This is because each time the original list of sentences gets passed to gsub.mult.

How can I construct a function / apply that will pass the previous apply to the next?

Comment: You could just slum it with a `for` loop...

Comment: Don't return anything in the function. Just feed the result of the `gsub` back to `data` instead of `obj`: `data <- gsub(to_replace[n], replace_with[n], data)`

Comment: @Rohit that works perfectly with a global assign. Guess there's probably no way to do this without a global assign which i know is typically frowned upon, but at least it works! Thanks!